# what is the best way update the dataset as user scrolls down and reaches the end of a the dataset?

Tags: java, android

Im fetching first dataset (i.e. List) from server url using `AsyncTask` in the `MainActivity`. Its passed into a `RecyclerView` from `onPostExecute()`.

When a user scrolls down and reaches the end, should I fetch the data from new url and update dataset by defining again a `AsyncTask` from the `RecyclerView.Adapter` class?

Note: the url returns list of 20 items. So I use the `position == 19`, to load the second dataset from the `onBindViewHolder`.

Is this the best approach ?

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.movieViewHolder> {

    public List<Movie> movies;
    private Context mContext;
    boolean page=true;

    public MovieAdapter(Context c, List<Movie> mov) {
        mContext = c;
        movies = mov;
    }

    public void MovieAdapterUpdate(List<Movie> movie) {
        movies = movie;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(movieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position == 19 && page) {
            new fetchMovieTask().execute("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b2118ec71368ce33306b3bcdc524d7ac&language=en-US&page=2");
            page=false;
        }

        Log.i("test", String.valueOf(position));
        Movie currentMovie = movies.get(position);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(currentMovie.getMovieThumbnail()).into(holder.moviePoster);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("size", String.valueOf(movies.size()));
        return movies.size();
    }

    public class fetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Movie>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(strings[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movie) {
            movies.addAll(movie);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

    public final String URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b2118ec71368ce33306b3bcdc524d7ac&language=en-US&page=1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Movie>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

        new fetchMovieTask().execute(URL);
    }

    public class fetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Movie>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Movie> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return QueryUtils.fetchMovieData(strings[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Movie> movies) {
           movieAdapter.MovieAdapterUpdate(movies);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ideal question for Stackoverflow. But anyway, I'm writing an answer to point a potential problem with your design.

You've started an `AsyncTask` in your `onBindViewHolder` which is dirty and erroneous. Because, for the first set of data it'll work fine I think, but when you've 40 items already then you need to put another condition for that telling the adapter that when the `position == 39` fetch the third dataset of next 20 items and so on.

So make it a bit dynamic detecting the end of your scroll and call a function to get the next dataset, add the fetched items in with your `List` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

There are plenty libraries which handles these types of endless scrolling. I think you might be looking for something like [this](https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll). Here's a [nice article](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) explaining the behaviour too.